# how to rotate mutiple rectangle coordinates around image center

Tags: python, image, numpy, scipy

When it comes to test a computer vision algorithm object detection, by rotating a test image one can detect some missed objects. By doing so, those detected object locations represented by (x,y) coordinates for each point in rectangles should be rotated back. The output of object detector is a Numpy array which contains e.g. 100 elements which each one has 4 pair points representing (x,y) coordinates of rectangles around detected objects i.e. a Numpy array with (100,8) shape. These objects were detected in rotated version of original images. Therefore, they have to be rotated back for visualization on original image. The original image has 5616x3744px resolution and so rotated version with e.g. 90 degree has 3744x5616px.

- each row is like [x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4]

The question is how we can rotate all of these points in one line around image center which let's consider to be (2808,1872). When I run the following code, Python throws an error of `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1000,8) (2,)` which makes sense. Speed is important in this case. So I am trying to avoid using `for` loops.

```
def Rotate2D(pts,cnt,degree):
    ang = math.radians(degree)
    '''pts = {} Rotates points(nx2) about center cnt(2) by angle ang(1) in radian'''
    return scipy.dot(pts-cnt,scipy.array([[scipy.cos(ang),scipy.sin(ang)],[-scipy.sin(ang),scipy.cos(ang)]]))+cnt
```

Comment: @MateenUlhaq I just added a scipy tag

Comment: @U8-Forward I remove redundant part, but I do not know why I should change 1872. In my case 1872 is needed.

Comment: @U8-Forward I think the edit thing glitched out and made it look like you changed one of the numbers.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq How come i didn't change the numbers

Comment: So, when you say _"100 elements which each one has 8 points representing `(x,y)` "_ do you mean that each row in the array contains 4 (not 8) points (i.e., pairs of `x` and `y`) such as `x1`, `y1`, `x2`, `y2`,  `x3`, `y3`, `x4`, `y4`. Is this correct?

Comment: @AGNGazer Yes, I modified the question accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are trying to subtract "center" - a 2-element vector from a `(100, 8)` "array of coordinates". In what space? 8D? If so, the center also should be a list of 8 coordinates because a point in an 8D space is defined by providing its coordinates along each of the 8 axes.

Your code works if the array of coordinates is of shape `(100, 2)`.

---

If, when you say *"100 elements which each one has 8 points representing `(x,y)`"* you mean that each row in the array contains 4 (not 8) points (i.e., pairs of `x` and `y`) such as `x1`, `y1`, `x2`, `y2`, `x3`, `y3`, `x4`, `y4`, then the best way to deal with this is to reshape your `pts` array:

```
import numpy as np
def Rotate2D(pts, cnt, degree):
    ang = math.radians(degree)
    m = scipy.array([[scipy.cos(ang), scipy.sin(ang)],
                     [-scipy.sin(ang), scipy.cos(ang)]])
    rpts = scipy.dot(np.reshape(pts, (pts.size // 2, 2)) - cnt, m) + cnt
    rpts = np.reshape(rpts, pts.shape)
```

Comment: they need to be roated in 2D space of image. I have updated my question. You can check it. I assume now it is clear what the question is. How can I reshape center.x and center.y image to 8D space?

Comment: thanks alot. It worked. However, it is needed to substract center.x and center.y before applying this function and adding new center.x and center.y afterwards.  I will put the full solution down below. Thanks again man! :)

Comment: @MajidAzimi What do you mean that you _"needed to substract `center.x` and `center.y` before applying this function"_? Do you see parameter `cnt` and what it is doing? I used the same variable name  `cnt` (as opposite to something more human, such as `center`) because that is how _you called it in your example_ (!).

Comment: I have explained why I changed it. Maybe what I did is wrong and I did not notice cnt. Please consider that all of Xs and Ys should be subtracted by width and height to be shifted to center. Then those points should be added with width and height of original image. I think this problem was caused due to my poor explanation. I will update the question right away. Please read through my comments in the solution above and if they make sense please edit your solution accordingly. Then I will delete mine. Thanks again for your help to answer this question and sorry if what I did made you upset :)

Answer (score -1):

With the help of @AGNGazer, this question was answered.
It is needed first to shift all of point to be around center: [0, 0]
Let us consider a 2 objects rather than 100 ones for the sake of simplicity and 90 degree rotation.

```
old_coord = np.zeros((2,8))
old_coord [0] = [500, 500, 510, 500, 510, 510, 500, 510] # only filling one is enough to show the functionality.
```

shift to center using rotated image centers [1872,2808].

```
old_coord [:, list(range(0, 8, 2))] -= 1872
old_coord [:, list(range(1, 8, 2))] -= 2808
```

apply @AGNGazer 's function.

```
new_coord = Rotate2D(old_coord, [0, 0], 90)
```

shift to original image centere [1872, 2808]

```
new_coord [:, list(range(1, 8, 2))] += 1872
new_coord [:, list(range(0, 8, 2))] +=  2808
>>> new_coord
array([[5116.,  500., 5116.,  510., 5106.,  510., 5106.,  500.],
   [0.,  0., 0.,  0., 0.,  0., 0.,  0.]])
```

Comment: I am disappointed, really. I did exactly what you have asked (rotate multiple coordinates) and my code includes shift of coordinates before matrix multiplication - see second line from last (`rpts = scipy.dot(np.reshape(pts, (pts.size // 2, 2)) - cnt, m) + cnt`). You just should call my function and provide the coordinates `new_coord = Rotate2D(old_coord, [1872, 2808], 90)`. What you seem to be doing is actually using my code incorrectly and then trying to fix it from outside and pretend that you have improved something.

Comment: @ Hi AGN Gazer, sorry I did not mean anything. I just noticed there is a problem in the code which you had sent which was not from your side,but due to my poor explanation. I removed the tag for the solution and tagged your solution and final solution. However, please edit your solution to be completely accurate. Let me explain what is the problem. Maybe I got it wrong and your code was already correct.Well in my case I had rotated the image by90 and detected some objects then I needed to rotated those detected bounding boxes to show object locations in the original image.see the comment below

Comment: The point is that those x1y1..x4y4 coordinates should be first translated to center point (0,0) in the image by subtracting width and height of rotated image and then get rotated. After rotation they should be translated back using the new center image coordinate i.e. width and height of original image. I would like to ask you to consider these points in your solution. Then I will delete my solution. sorry again for that :)